# Android: Network Radio off before ACTION_SHUTDOWN event.Events order Changed in ICS

Tags: android, android-intent

I was sending logout to my server when user did a power off on the device.The order of events in **2.3 and 4.0.3** are as follows.So now Log out is Failed.

Device : **Samsung Galaxy s2**

Android : 2.3

1)Receive ACTION_SHUTDOWN  

2) Send Logout event,sleep for 5 secs,**LOG OUT SENT SUCCESSFULLY**

3)Data Network Radio off event.

4)Device Power off.

Android : 4.0.3

1) Data Network Radio off event.

2)Receive ACTION_SHUTDOWN 

3) Send Logout event,**LOG OUT FAIL As Network is down**.

Any way around to get ACTION_SHUTDOWN  before Data Network Radio off?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like vanilla Android behavior. May be your device's manufacturer did some internal improvements to the shutdown process to speed it up.

You can see how shutdown is handled at [frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/pm/ShutdownThread.java#L296](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/java/com/android/server/pm/ShutdownThread.java#L296) on current master branch.

However as a mobile application developer you shouldn't rely on constant network connection.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a Service for that? You could register an ever-running service so that when it receives onDestroy() you know your app is being killed and do that logout request.

Just an idea. I don't know whether service's onDestroy() gets called earlier than network goes down, but I'd give it a try just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Create a service that receives the broadcast for the shutdown like this:

```
public class MyAppShutdown extends BroadcastReceiver{
    private static final String TAG = "MyAppShutdown";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v(TAG, "onReceive - ++ ENTER ++");
        if (intent != null && intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN)){
            Log.v(TAG, "onReceive - ***] SHUTDOWN [***");
            // perhaps send a broadcast to your app via intent to perform a log out.
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.addAction("intent.myapp.action.shutdown");
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
        Log.v(TAG, "onReceive - ++ LEAVE ++");        
    }
}
```

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`, embed this fragment below within the `<application>` tags:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyAppShutdown">
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.SHUTDOWN"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

From your app's activity register a broadcast receiver with the appropriate filter for intents:

```
public class myApp extends Activity{
    private myAppBroadcastRcvr myAppRcvr = new myAppBroadcastRcvr();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("intent.myapp.action.shutdown");
        registerReceiver(myAppRcvr, filter);
    }
    // Perhaps you have this
    private void LogOff(){
    }
    class myAppBroadcastRcvr extends BroadcastReceiver{
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
            if (intent.getAction().equals("intent.myapp.action.shutdown")){
                 LogOff();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oklets assume i call LogOff().As platform Network Radio is off, i am not able to send out data!!!

Comment: Yeah! I did somewhat realize after re-reading your question again... am surprised, cannot believe android changed it around, would have thought radio is the last thing to be shut down - sorry for the rambling post as its not what you're looking for...

Comment: thats Ok!!Yeah strange why the behavior was changed!!

Comment: http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/net/MobileDataStateTracker.java.shtml would this help you?